# C -> operator freezing in function call?

Tags: c, pointers, record

For a programming assignment I'm supposed to create a model student database. To initialize the database we have to write a function `InitDB` to allocate all the memory, etc. Here's what I wrote so far for `InitDB`: (included the `struct` stuff and `main()` just in case too)

```
typedef struct {
    double mathGrade;
    } stuDB;

typedef struct {
    int numStudents;
    stuDB students[MaxStudents];
    } classDB;

main(){
   int avGrade;
   classDB *example;
   InitDB(example);
   //printf("Average class grade is %d\n",AvGrade(example));   <----ignore
   getchar();
}

void InitDB(classDB *example){
 int i=-1,numS;
 printf("How many students?");
 scanf("%d",&(example->numStudents);
 stuDB *pstudents[numS]; //array of pointers to each student rec of type stuDB
 do {
    pstudents[i] = (stuDB *)malloc(sizeof(stuDB));
    if(pstudents[i]==NULL) break;
    i++;
    } while(i<numS);
 pstudents[0]->mathGrade = 42;     //just for testing
 pstudents[1]->mathGrade = 110;
}
```

When I run the program, it freezes at the 3rd line of `InitDB`, (the `scanf` line). When I say freezes, I mean it does the same thing my command prompt does if I make the second argument of `scanf` not a pointer variable. But `&(example->numStudents)` should already be a pointer...right? and so I'm out of ideas. Why is it doing this, and how can I fix it?

Also, I'm not quite sure I set up the `malloc` statement correctly but haven't really been able to see if it works because of the latter problem. Am I on the right track with that...or what?

Comment: `numS` seems to not have any value.

Comment: Your code is full of uninitialized values ... how can you expect it to work? Set the warning levels high in your compiler so it will warn you about these sorts of mistakes. Although it probably won't warn you about `i` being initialized to -1 and then being used as an index.

Comment: @TonyTheLion The OP seems to have assumed that example->numStudents will magically jump into numS.

Comment: @Jim Balter No, I was trying other stuff and accidentally left that there. I got rid of it in my program though... sorry :/

Comment: It's your responsibility to post what you're actually running, and will make it a lot more likely that you'll get sensible answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include<stdio.h>

// structure to hold mathgrade 
typedef struct 
{
   double mathGrade;
}stuDB;

// structure to hold students and their grades
typedef struct 
{
    int numStudents;   //no of students
    stuDB students[];  //array of stuDB
}classDB;

int main()
{
    classDB *example;
    InitDB(&example);
    printAvgDB(example);
    return 0;   
}

// Calculate Avg of all students and print it
void printAvgDB(classDB *example)
{
   int i;
   double avg=0.0;
   for(i=0;i<example->numStudents;i++)
      avg+=example->students[i].mathGrade;
   printf("\nAverage: %lf",avg/example->numStudents);
}

// Initiate no of students and get their mathgrade
void InitDB(classDB **ex)
{
   int i,numS;
   printf("How many students?:");
   scanf("%d",&numS);
   // Allocate array size indirectly
   classDB *example=(classDB *)malloc(sizeof(int)+numS*sizeof(stuDB));
   example->numStudents=numS;
   for(i=0;i<example->numStudents;i++)
   {
       printf("\nEnter math grade for student[%d]:",i+1);
       scanf("%lf",&example->students[i].mathGrade);      
   }
*ex=example;
}
```

Comment: This is no good ... you must allocate enough space for the number of students, but the caller of InitDB doesn't know that info... And your edit isn't any better. I suggest that you wait until you have tested, working code before posting it in an answer. Hint: don't malloc until *after* reading the number of students.

Comment: @JimBalter it is fine working code. He have initialized array for no of students with defining the MaxStudents. SO only i left it as it is. Even it can be determined dynamically.

Comment: Ah, ok, you're right. But it would be better to just return the pointer rather than stuffing it into a `**` argument.

Comment: And now if user enters the number of students greater than MaxStudents you write past the end of the students array.

Comment: Returning a value is objectively better than stuffing into a variable pointed to by a parameter by numerous measures. I await the day when functional programming takes over and wipes away the mindbogglingly atrocious practices of so many C programmers.

Comment: @yurish "now"? That's an issue in the OP's code (and another reason that continuing to teach C to new programmers is such a horrid idea).

Comment: @Jim Balter. He gave the answer by rewriting the OP's code. I can understand why new programmer makes this mistake but do not understand why knowledgeable person giving the answer replicates this (BTW don't see anything wrong with teaching C. Programer must understand low level concepts.

Comment: @I only questioned your word "now"; yeash. And it's easy to teach people low level concepts without teaching them obsolete crap programming languages. I've been programming since 1965, 35 of them in C, was on the C standards committee, and I could write a few books on why teaching C is so harmful.

Comment: @It's off topic, but C is not obsolete. It's a main language in embedded programming even now days.

Answer (score 5):

There is no instance of classDB - just a pointer to classDB.
Change the code to-:

```
   classDB example;
   InitDB(&example);
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot! But I have another question...so now I want to average the mathGrades over the two students, within another function AvGrade. (from the line commented out) How to I refer to the ith student's math grade?? 

I tried **example->students[i].mathGrade** but it just kept returning memory addresses. And two nonconsecutive ones at that. Does that mean the malloc function above isn't working right? And more to the point, what expression can I use to get the mathGrade correctly this time?

Comment: @Thornshadow17432 Your expression is right but you didn't put anything into mathGrade so you're getting junk values (not memory addresses) ... malloc doesn't initialize memory.

Comment: @Thornshadow17432 Then again, it might be because pstudents is local to InitDB so all those mallocs are lost (leaked) when it returns.

Comment: @Thornshadow17432 You can check the below code to get it working.

Comment: @Jim Balter So how do I initialize the values, in InitDB(), without losing the values? For that matter, since pstudents is completely useless since all the info is lost when the function closes, how can I store the pointers to the different students' rows without losing them? Or is it possible to have the elements in students[] be pointed to by each of those pointers returned by malloc()...?

Comment: @Amarnath Krishnan No, I saw your code, but I think I'm required to allocate the memory inside of InitDB somehow?

Comment: @Thornshadow17432 you have to create a pointer for the classDB and pass it into InitDB so that you can directly store data in the memory and acess it.

Comment: @Thornshadow17432 if creating pointer inside initDB is you case than you can work on double pointers. Check the edit.

Comment: @Thornshadow17432 InitDB should malloc an array of `classDB`s (which gives you a `classDB*`), initialize them, and return that pointer. Or (not as good) you can pass in a `classDB**` and store the malloced `classDB*` into the pointer that it points to. But the current signature for InitDB is unworkable.

Comment: @Thornshadow17432 Ignore my comment and just look at Amarnath's answer.